# Calorimetry Question

Tags: mathematical-physics

If you are familiar with the formula q = (m) * (c) * (Delta Temperature)
q = (Delta Heat)
m = Mass
c = Heat Capacity
Delta T = Change in temperature

The question is asking to solve with this info:

The heat capacity is 440 KJ/Degrees Celcius. The energy added is a total of 24480 J and it asks to solve for change in temperature. Any tips?

Comment: Q=c*dT for this question, not Q=mc*dt because heat capacity is given and not specific heat capacity. Just convert C and Q to equivalent units, plug it into the equation and solve for change in T.

Comment: But how do I do that? @Jonathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q=c*dt

Q=24.48 KJ

C=440KJ

dt=?

24.48=440dt

24.48/440=dt

dt= .05563

Therefore change in temperature is approximately .05563 degrees celsius or kelvin.

Comment: How about mass, where is that involved?

Comment: This article explains the difference between specific heat capacity and heat capacity http://www.differencebetween.net/science/difference-between-specific-heat-and-heat-capacity/. Your question involved heat capacity. The formula for heat capacity is q=c*dt. Heat capacity doesn't involve mass. Specific heat capacity does.